[Super]+P what is executed when selecting mirror screen
I can press Super+P to mirror or extend my screen. My question is, what is executed when doing this?
Is that a script? Is it a dbus-message? Could I find that somewhere in the code?
Anyway I would like to know what is executed on selecting "mirror" when clicking Super+P
mirror,extend,... screen

What is a [Super] key?

@user628388 a lot of keyboards have a Windows symbol on that key
